# Selecting children nodes

Tags: dom, css-selectors, jsoup

How can I select the following element in order to insert a new element?

NOTE: Assume valid <tr> and <td> for the nested tables and inserting the <pre> tag.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tbody>
        ....more elements here...
        <table>
          <tbody> <----- how do I select this?

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  <body>
</html>
```

The following select isn't working?

```
// This isn't selecting the node correctly?
Element tablebody = doc.body().select("table  > tbody > table > tbody").first();

Element pre = tablebody.appendElement("pre");
pre.text("hello");
```

Comment: "Assume valid <tr> and <td> for [...] inserting the <pre> tag." That is clearly not possible given your code. Your code is clearly showing inserting a `pre` in a `tbody` element. You can't just make assumptions on paper and pretend your code will work based on those assumptions (unless jsoup knows how to work around it on its own).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not valid markup. A `table` cannot exist directly inside a `tbody`.

If your inner table isn't in a `tr > td`, then that inner table is actually being constructed as a next sibling of the outer table. In other words, you don't actually have an inner table at all.

Unless the markup can be corrected, you have to treat that "inner table" as a following sibling:

```
Element tablebody = doc.body().select("table + table > tbody").first();
```

If you can correct the markup, you can either complete the selector with the missing `tr` and `td` bits:

```
Element tablebody = doc.body().select("table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody").first();
```

Or simply replace one of the child selectors with a descendant selector:

```
Element tablebody = doc.body().select("table > tbody table > tbody").first();
```

Additionally, a `tbody` can only have `tr` elements as children. You cannot append a `pre` element inside a `tbody` the way you're trying to do. You probably want to select the first `tr > td` in *that* `tbody` and append it there.

Comment: thx for the great summary. .select("table > tbody table > tbody").first(); worked perfectly!